# PerformanceCounterCategory USB is MultiInstance, but no instances are found

Tags: c#, exception, instance, performancecounter

I'm playing with PerformanceCounters in C#. I already collected information about Processor and Memory and it was fine.
Now, i wanted to check USB PerformanceCounterCategory. here's what i did:

```
        System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory Category = new System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory("USB",".");
        string[] instanceNames = Category.GetInstanceNames();
        List<PerformanceCounter> countersList_temp = new List<PerformanceCounter>();
        if (instanceNames.Length == 0)
        {
             countersList_temp.AddRange(Category.GetCounters());
        }
        else
        {
              for (int i = 0; i < instanceNames.Length; i++)
              {
                     countersList_temp.AddRange(Category.GetCounters(instanceNames[i]));
              }
        }                                                  

        foreach (performanceCounter counter in countersList_temp)
        {
             counter.NextValue();
        }
```

For the above code, I get an Exception `InvalidOperationException` when calling `counter.NextValue();` It's description is: `Counter is not single instance, an instance name needs to be specified.`
I didn't include any further code, which displays the collected values, because it's not what's important here.

During debugging, I saw, that Category object (which is USB category) has CategoryType property set to `MultiInstance`. But `instanceNames[]` array is empty! `Category.GetInstanceNames();` does not return any instance for USB category. So why the property says `MultiInstance`? I think that's the issue and I have no idea how to deal with that.

Comment: Is it not possible to change the instance type? E.g. `counter.CategoryType = PerformanceCounterCategoryType.SingleInstance;` Or specify it to not allow multi instance during initialization: e.g. `PerformanceCounter pc = new PerformanceCounter(myCategory, myCounter, false);`.

Comment: CategoryType is a property of PerformanceCounterCategory class, not PerformanceCounter. I don't initialize each counter, I use GetCounters() method, so i don't use PerformanceCounter constructor

Comment: I can't initialize USB counter like you said. For example: PerformanceCounter usbCounter = new PerformanceCounter("USB", "Bulk Bytes/Sec", false); would give me an exception, because only custom counters can be not read-only